# jQuery post from php variable

Tags: php, jquery-plugins

I'm in the process of creating a 'drag-and-drop' ordering list, and I grabbed some code for an existing one and I need to modify it to fit my needs. However I do not fully understand exactly what the code is doing in order to modify it correctly.

Basically I have a php variable '$draft_id' that I need to pass into my `updateList.php`. If I just define `$draft_id=0` within `updateList.php` it works fine, but I need to be able to pass this value in.

The code looks like:

(index.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function slideout(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#response").slideUp("slow", function () {});
    }, 2000);}
    $("#response").hide();
    $(function() {
        $("#list ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move', update:function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update';
            $.post("updateList.php", order, function(theResponse){
                $("#response").html(theResponse);
                $("#response").slideDown('slow');
                slideout();
            });
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>

...

<?php
include("connect.php");
$draft_id='0';
$query  = "SELECT id, text FROM sort WHERE draft_id =" . $draft_id . " ORDER BY listorder ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   
   $id = stripslashes($row['id']);
   $text = stripslashes($row['text']);
   echo "<li id='arrayorder_" . $id . "'>" . $text;
   echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
   echo "</li>";
}
?>
```

(updateList.php)

```
<?php 
include("connect.php");
$array  = $_POST['arrayorder'];
if ($_POST['update'] == "update"){
     $count = 1;
        //------------------------------------
        $draft_id=$_POST['draft_id'];
        //------------------------------------
        foreach ($array as $idval) {
        $query = "UPDATE sort SET listorder = " . $count . " WHERE id = " . $idval . " AND draft_id=" . $draft_id;
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        $count ++;  
    }
    echo 'Draft Order Saved!';
    }
?>
```

So basically in the 'updateList.php' I'd like 'draft_id' to be taken from the $_POST array, but I'm not sure how to pass it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've figured out how pass this how it needs to be passed, so I figured I'd share in case anyone else needs it in the future. So my main issue was that I did not understand exactly how the $_POST array was being set.

In the Javascript there is a $.post that is using a variable 'order' which is defined above it. This is where the $_POST array is being passed. So by adding an additional condition you can pass additional variables in the $_POST array.

So I changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function slideout(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#response").slideUp("slow", function () {});
}, 2000);}
$("#response").hide();
$(function() {
    $("#list ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move', update:function() {
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update';
        $.post("updateList.php", order, function(theResponse){
            $("#response").html(theResponse);
            $("#response").slideDown('slow');
            slideout();
        });
    }
  });
  });
});
</script>
```

to:

```
<?php   //this will later be pulled from another page, but for now
$draft_id='0';  //I just set it up for testing purposes.
$_POST['draft_id']=$draft_id;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function slideout(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#response").slideUp("slow", function () {});
}, 2000);}
$("#response").hide();
$(function() {
    $("#list ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move', update:function() {

    //we will add &draft_id='the php variable $draft_id to the order variable'

        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update' + '&draft_id=<?php echo $draft_id; ?>';
        $.post("updateList.php", order, function(theResponse){
            $("#response").html(theResponse);
            $("#response").slideDown('slow');
            slideout();
        });
    }
  });
  });
});
</script>
```

This fixed my issue, hopefully this can help someone out in the future if they run into this same issue.